# What should we do with broken links?

Tags: discussion

Reviewing the suggested edit queue, I bumped into a question where a user replaced one of the links because the former one was broken. However, as it *already* was broken (and out of Google's cache), I couldn't verify if the new link is a valid replacement for the first one, so I rejected the edit.

I was looking here on meta for a policy towards broken links, and also on StackExchange meta, where I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105128/how-to-handle-link-rot-and-broken-links). However, this only talks about StackOverflow.

Is the same procedure valid on SuperUser as well? I mean:

- Is it ok trying to find a link replacement and edit the question if possible?
- Should we provide the link as a comment?

Comment: It's fine to fix broken links. Just make sure you complete the edit summary to say "Fixed broken link" ;)

Comment: And what about suggested edits where we cannot confirm that the new links are analogous to the broken ones? Should we skip, reject them?

Comment: If the replacement is also broken then reject the edit. I would select "causes harm - replacement link also broken"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can find what's definitely the (or a) correct link, it's fine to go ahead and fix it. If you can't find it on the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/web/) or Google, and it seems *correct enough* and posted with good intentions, better that than a broken link IMO. The person who posted the posted the post can always fix it in the future.

If it's a link only answer, flag it, and we'll make it go away.

Comment: Conversely, if the user is editing in a spam link then flag it and we'll make *them* go away.